# jquery autocomplete \t (tab) in result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, tabs

I'm using jquery-ui autocomplete. it exceeded my expectations,improved the user experience and worked good for about one month until suddenly it started to append tabs (\t) in some results.

Some results come alright and some with appended tag in the beginning of them.

[This is a good completion](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/2047/uvrg.png)

[This is a bad completion (with tab)](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/4227/kr4b.png)

this is how i set the autocompletion to my input:

```
$( "#id" ).autocomplete(
{
source: collection
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you *sure* it's a tab and not a CSS change that has caused it? Are you sure it is not in your data source?

Comment: Yes im sure... i know that because if i save the data, my database shows the result with the tab appended in the beginning..
And about the source (aka the collection) ive done some checks to assure its safe and tab free.. i printed out the collection and it came tab free..